How can I fix the typescript handles function overloading and type inference
I have this playground and I want to make it works in my case.
type Person = {
  name: string;
  surname: string;
}

type User = Person & {
  username: string; 
}

type Name = string;

function createLogin(user: User, value: { nickName: string }): string;
function createLogin(user: Person, value: { name: string }): string;
function createLogin(user: any, value: any): string {
  return "It's not important";
}

const user: User = {
  name: "",
  surname: "",
  username: "",
};
const person: Person = {
  name: "",
  surname: "",
};

const result = createLogin(person, { name: "" });
const result2 = createLogin(user, { name: "" }); // <--- The problem is here
const result3 = createLogin(user, { nickName: "" });

My problem is that for the result2 with the user of type User (which is a superset of Person), the second argument { name: "" } matches the second overload signature. TypeScript chooses the more specific overload that matches both the argument types, but I want to avoid this from happening.
Thank you in advance for your time and help, it is greatly appreciated.

You can't prevent or avoid that. Instead you should make the second overload accept a NonUser, which is a Person without a defined username, as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a duplicate; if not, what's missing?

The problem that User extends Person so accepted as Person, read about structural typing. To solve the issue there are several ways:
Use an optional never:
Playground
type BasePerson = {
  name: string;
  surname: string;
}

type Person = BasePerson & {
  username?: never;
}

type User = BasePerson & {
  username: string;
}

Accept only strict types:
Playground
type StrictType<A extends object, B extends object> = A extends B ? B extends A ? A : never : never;

function createLogin<T extends User>(user: StrictType<T, User>, value: { nickName: string }): string;
function createLogin<T extends Person>(user: StrictType<T, Person>, value: { name: string }): string;
function createLogin(user: any, value: any): string {
  return "It's not important";
}

Use a conditional type for the argument (similar to the strict type):
Playground
function createLogin(user: User, value: { nickName: string }): string;
function createLogin<T extends Person>(user: T, value: Person extends T ? { name: string } : never): string;
function createLogin(user: any, value: any): string {
  return "It's not important";
}

